# Why did Lufthansa stop flying between Istanbul and Munich?

Tags: istanbul, munich, lufthansa

I had some flights with Lufthansa from Istanbul (IST) to Munich (MUC) about 2 years ago. There were several flights a day, but there isn't any for a while.

Why did Lufthansa stop flying between Istanbul and Munich? Is there any announcement for it?

Comment: -1 for a "please look this up for me so I don't have to" type of question.

Comment: You're asking us to read the minds of airline executives. That is not a good kind of question for this site. Voting to close as "primiarily opinion-based".

Comment: Most probably because there was not enough demand.

Comment: (Note that Lufthansa's Star Alilance partner Turkish Airlines does fly this route several times a day).

Comment: @fkraiem Not relevant. I already googled for it, but found nothing (at least in English).

Comment: Lack of demand on the city pair? Better use of aircraft?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't agree. You are assuming that Lufthansa has not revealed the reason. Even if they didn't, market analysts may have data.

Comment: So you think that Lufthansa market analysts sit here and will answer your question?

Comment: @Neusser No. I expect someone knows an article that I can't find (maybe the article is in German).

Comment: These flights stopped during the winder 2015 and there were a bunch of articles in the German media. Basically falling passenger numbers (compounded by the 2015 Ankara bombing) and increased competition from Turkish Airlines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found an answer on [CNN Türk](https://www.cnnturk.com/ekonomi/sirketler/lufthansa-izmir-munih-seferlerine-basladi).

It seems that Lufthansa cancelled flights not only from Istanbul, but also from Ankara and Izmir due to low demand. In April 2017, Izmir-Munich flights restarted. According to **Lufthansa Turkey General Manager Kemal Geçer**, Istanbul-Munich and Ankara-Munich flights also will restart as soon as the demand recovers.

Extra information: The number of German visitors decreased 27.6% in 2016 compared to 2015. The [border stats](http://www.kultur.gov.tr/EN,153018/number-of-arriving-departing-visitors-foreigners-and-ci-.html) show that the number already started to recover, for example 10.8% up in June 2017 compared to June 2016.